# C# utf8-encoding bytearray out of range

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays, utf8-decode

I have the following problem: if the `String` contains a `char` that is not known from `ASCII`, it uses a 63.

Because of that i changed the encoding to `UTF8`, but I know a `char` can have the `length` of two `bytes`, so I get a out of range error.
How can I solve the problem?

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

byte[] baInput = enc.GetBytes(strInput);

// Split byte array (6 Byte) in date (days) and time (ms) parts
byte[] baMsec = new byte[4];
byte[] baDays = new byte[2];

for (int i = 0; i < baInput.Length; i++)
{
    if (4 > i)
    {
        baMsec[i] = baInput[i];
    }
    else
    {
        baDays[i - 4] = baInput[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `strInput`?

Comment: The content for example is: l¦h*

Comment: It looks like you're working with bytes, not text. Don't use a string to store it in the first place, but a byte array. How do you obtain the `strInput` in the first place?

Comment: Is `|` part of the string?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The question you should be asking (and that eventually leads to your solution) is: *"What character encoding does my source string have?"*. Everything else is just guesswork, that's not useful for anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you *seem* to be having is that you know the number of characters, but not the number of bytes, when using UTF8. To solve just that problem, you could use:

```
byte[] baMsec = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInput.SubString(0, 4));
byte[] baDays = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInput.SubString(4));
```

Comment: the `strInput` contains §║ ê or l¦h*

Comment: @xproseal thanks, I edited my question when I saw sample data. It might be wise to try and figure out what encoding was originally used to construct that data, and use that encoding yourself.

Comment: My answer* not question :P

Answer (score 1):

**Recommended Solution:**

1) Split the `strInput` using the `SubString(Int32, Int32)` method and get the date and time parts in separate `String` variables, say `strDate` and `strTime`.

2) Then call `UTF8Encoding.GetBytes` on `strDate` and `strTime` and collect the byte array in `baDays` and `baMsec` respectively.

**Why this works:**

C# `String` is by default `UTF-16` encoded, which is equally good to represent non-ASCII characters. Hence, no data is lost.

**General Caution:**

Never try to directly manipulate encoded strings at byte-level, you'll get lost. Use the `String` and `Encoding` class methods of C# to get the bytes if you want bytes.

**Alternate approach:**

I'm wondering (like others) why your date-time data contains non-numeric characters. I saw in a comment that you get your data from `reader["TIMESTAMP2"].ToString();` and the sample content is `§║ ê or l¦h`. Check if you are interpreting numeric data stored in `reader["TIMESTAMP2"]` as `String` by mistake and should you actually treat it as a numeric type. Otherwise, even with this method, you'll be getting unexpected output soon.

Comment: [That answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38047841/993547) was already given a few minutes ago.

Comment: I know. It appeared while I was composing my answer. Should I delete mine?

Comment: That would be a possibility, yes. You can also extend your answer to give more information, information that wasn't provided in a previous answer. That would make your answer stand out.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I was trying to stick to giving the answer concisely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `baInput` can contain more values than both `baDays` and `baMsec` can contain. After 6 iterations, you run out of the array size. Hence, the exception.

When you hit the seventh iteration, you get `i - 4` which yields `6 - 4` = `2`.

Since `baDays` only has two items, you can set the values on index 0 and 1.

Comment: You explained the problem, but you did not give a solution.

Comment: It really depends. You could read at most 6 bytes, but then you would truncate data. Probably OP needs to extend the array so all the characters can be read. For UTF-8 that would mean doubling the array size would do. Possibly it is an option to prevent happening this at all by forcing the data to be in ASCII, since the data seems to be time stamps.